# how to write a function in dart language that returns a Future with a List of Jobs from GitHub job?

Tags: flutter, dart, github

GitHub Jobs has an open API for querying software engineering-related job positions. The following URL returns a list of remote jobs:

```
https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?location=remote
```

Given the following simple data class, in which you only care about the company name and job title,how to write a function that returns a Future with a List of Jobs?

```
class Job {
   Job(this.company, this.title);
   final String company;
   final String title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert'; 
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<List<Job>> fetchJobs() async { 
   final host = 'jobs.github.com'; 
   final path = 'positions.json'; 
   final queryParameters = {'location': 'remote'}; 
   final headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}; 
   final uri = Uri.https(host, path, queryParameters); 
   final results = await http.get(uri, headers: headers); 
   final jsonList = json.decode(results.body) as List; 
   return jsonList.map((job) => Job.fromJson(job)).toList(); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your response. Even though your answer may solve the question, it is better than you add an explanation. Also, please edit your answer mark your code as code so that it will be readable better.